# How to set NODE_PATH to $(pwd) when debugging in vscode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm currently using the following script to startup my nodejs application. I thereafter attach the vscode debugger to it, this works:

```
"dev": "NODE_PATH=\"$(pwd)\" NODE_ENV=development nodemon -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill --nolazy --debug-brk=36598 ./src/index.js"
```

I'd like to however use the inbuilt "launch" option in vscode.

In the launch.json under configurations under a configuration there is a field called env. I'd like to add the NODE_PATH there setting it's value to the current directory.

```
{
    "name": "Launch",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/index.js",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "args": [],
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "preLaunchTask": null,
    "runtimeExecutable": null,
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "-r",
        "babel-register",
        "-r",
        "babel-polyfill",
        "--nolazy"
    ],
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development",
        "NODE_PATH": "$(pwd)" // <--- here
    },
    "console": "internalConsole",
    "sourceMaps": false,
    "outDir": null
}
```

The issue here is that the variable is actually set to "$(pwd)" instead of running it as a command and saving the output.

When I have the following in my code:

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_PATH);
```

It outputs the following (instead of the current directory path):

```
$(pwd) // <--- wrong, I was expecting '/home/karl/dev/my_project'
```

I tried setting `"NODE_PATH=\"$(pwd)\"",` in the runtimeArgs and args but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> {
>
> ```
> "version": "0.2.0",
> "configurations": [
>     {
>         "type": "node",
>         "request": "launch",
>         "name": "Launch Program",
>         "program": "/Path_to_start_file/main.js",
>         "env":{
>             "NODE_PATH": "/Path_to_node_modules/node_modules"
>         }
>     }
> ] }
> ```

This Solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

You might also try "runtimeExecutable": "your/path/to/bin/node"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `${cwd}` - the task runner's current working directory on startup, as specified on
[VS Code Variable substitution](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_variable-substitution)

so in your case

```
"NODE_PATH": "${cwd}"
```